# Resolution Issues & Non Responsive Computer After Logging In From Locked OS

Tags: release-freya, greeter

Title says it all, my computer goes to sleep like normal, opens a crisp login screen. When I log in, pantheon goes to the lowest resolution. I have control of the cursor, but nothing responds to a click. Have to fully discharge the computer and reboot to fix the issue. This is a 3 day old installation, and nothing has been messed with.

Comment: Could you give some informations about your computer, graphics and graphics driver, for example